# Facebook App as Page Tab constantly gives an error

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I am trying to add a Tab to a Facebook Fan Page.

I registered as a developer, and created an app.
In the upper part I filled out Display Name, Namespace, Contact Email and I selected Apps for Pages as my category.

In the integration part I selected the Page Tab section. Filled out the Page Tab Name, Page Tab URL, Secure Tab URL and selected a Page Tab Image.

Saved everything and noted the App-ID.

When I however logon to facebook using the fan-page-account and call up the URL https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=MY_APP_ID&next=www.facebook.com I constantly get an error stating: "An error occurred with DISPLAY_NAME_OF_MY_APP. Please try again later."

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that Facebook has made another change and has not informed anyone.  Below is a new link that appears to work.  Just replace APP-ID with your application ID.

https://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key={APP-ID}&pages=1

Comment: THANKS! THIS WORKED! I thought I was going crazy. :)

They haven't even updated their own documentation. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/